# How many of the subsets of set $A$ are also subsets of set $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A=\left\{2,3,4,5,7,8\right\}$

$B=\left\{3,4,5,7,10\right\}$

How many of the subsets of set $A$ are also subsets of set $B$?

I find $2^4=16$. Because, $A∩B=\left\{3,4,5,7\right\}$.
But, the answer is $32$. But, why? Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. it cannot be $2^5$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thank you. Our formula is $2^n$. Isn't it?

Comment: What is $ n ?$ as an exponent.

Comment: @Elementary: Yes, if you mean that the number of subsets of an $n$-element set is $2^n$.

Comment: its important to understand why the formula is 2^n. Because there are two choices, whether or not each of the elements of $A∩B$ is in the subset. There are 4 elements in the intersection so there are $2^4$  different sets that can be made from the elements in the intersection

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah The number of all subsets of the set with a length of $"n".$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you Professor.

Comment: @Elementary: You’re welcome.

Comment: @justaguy I understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are your $2^{\#A\cap B}= 2^4=16,$ subsets
$$\emptyset$$
$$\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{7\}$$
$$\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{3,7\}$$
$$\{4,5\},\{4,7\},\{5,7\}$$
$$\{3,4,5\},\{3,4,7\},\{3,5,7\},\{4,5,7\}$$
$$\{3,4,5,7\}=A\cap B$$

Comment: But, in your answer there are $15$ sets?

Comment: @Elementary I just added the $16^{\text{th}}$ which is $\{3,5,7\}$. Thanks.